# Convert this display name to SPUser

Tags: spuser

How to convert this display name to SPUser type.

My input is Sivakumar, Piratheban (ext)(domain\user)

Comment: If it is a string you can user SPUser user=web.EnsureUser(input).

Comment: The EnsureUser method needs the login name. The string 'Sivakumar, Piratheban (ext)(domain\user)' would not fit into that. One should first parse out the login name from this kind of display name pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct convertion but you can use a regular expression to pull out the login name and then call EnsureUser on that.

```
var login = Regex.Match(input, @"\((?<login>[^\(\\]+\\[^\(\\]+)\)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture).Groups["login"].Value;
var user = web.EnsureUser(login);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could extract login name from input string using [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then initialize a user:

```
var loginName = input.Split('(', ')')[3];
var user = web.EnsureUser(loginName);
```

Comment: Living on the edge with not checking if you actually get four positions in the array resulting from the split ;)

Comment: I agree, no matter what input string will contain, the checking at least for the length of resulting array is a must ;)